# jQuery get one of not empty input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 inputs with same classes:

```
<input type="text" name="test" class="test">
<input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="test">
```

One of input is empty second - not. How I can get not empty input value ? Main rule, that input are absolutely same, I cant add some class or something else to define difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in conjection with [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) or Class selector

```
var nonEmptyInputs = $('input.test[name="test"]').filter(function(){
    return this.value.length > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop like

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var value;
  $('.test').each(function() {
    if (this.value.trim()) {
      value = this.value.trim()
      return false;
    }
  });
  snippet.log(value)
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test" class="test">
<input type="text" name="test" class="test" value="test">

<button>test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```js
    $(function(){
      $('button').click(function() {

        $.each($('.test'),function(){

           if( !$(this).val() )
               $(this).val('this text field was not filled');

        });

      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test" class="test">
<input type="text" name="test" class="test">

<button>test</button>
```